# Android Large Image With Gestures

Tags: android, image, zooming, gesture

I need to display a large image (3000x2000) with zoom and swipe gestures. Image is a map, so the key is performance and fluid motion.

Is there any control or library that does this well that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

which is able to load very large resolution images and also support scaling by gestures.